# NO VPN/PROXY How to cheat/fake IP location to google translate or websites

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i was surfing on omegle.com and finding only people from my country (Italy). I was wandering to chat with someone from US, DE, FR or similar since i know these languages, but cannot figure out how it finds out that i'm Italian. I think that it does it via google translate because it let you choose a language when you start chatting in upper right corner. So i was wondering... how to cheat on google translate and fake my language? I think it detects my ip location but i strictly don't want to use VPN or proxy for this experiment

what have i tried:

1- set chrome UI to english (de_DE)

2- start it with selenium+python with chromediver set with option add_argument("--lang=de-DE")

3- add_experimental_option("prefs", {"intl.accept_languages":"de,de_DE","translate_whitelists":{"de":"en"}})

4- change my windows input language to DE

nothing worked, do you have any other idea?

Comment: no, the only clause was no vps or proxy lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found out how, it was with google translate, setting 2 translate cookies when starting the webdriver did the trick